# Angular 7, Jasmine code-coverage does not include a function, while the test returns positive

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-material, angular7

I have a function closing the sidenav on backdrop click:

```
 public closeSidenav() {
    this.sidenav.toggle();
 }
```

And in the HTML:

```
<mat-sidenav-container (backdropClick)="closeSidenav()">
```

I'm testing the 'backdropClick' event in the following test:

```
it('should listen to a backdrop click and toggle the sidenav menu', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;

    app.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    spyOn(app, 'closeSidenav');

    const backdrop = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('div.mat-drawer-backdrop'));
    backdrop.triggerEventHandler('click', null);

    expect(app.closeSidenav).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The test returns positive but the function is not being covered in the code coverage. I have tried adding

```
    spyOn(app.sidenav, 'toggle');
    expect(app.sidenav.toggle).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

with no other outcome.

It's the last function in the file, and because of that I'm not getting the 100% coverage.

Just want to know what I might be missing.

Answer (score 1):

When using `triggerEventHandler`, you need to specify the event binding not the action - **backdropClick** not **click**:

```
<mat-sidenav-container (backdropClick)="closeSidenav()">

const container = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-sidenav-container'));
container.triggerEventHandler('backdropClick', null);
```

And to achieve actual code coverage, tell the spy to call the real code:

```
spyOn(app, 'closeSidenav').and.callThrough();
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. But whereas the test returns positive this way as well, the function gets no coverage anyway.

Comment: The spy traps the actual call to the real code. You can change that by appending `.and.callThrough()` to the `spyOn()` call. I've update my example.